# How to use fetch().then() to get Response body

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I need a `const` to define this body(string). Then I can use it to do like `console.log()`

```
fetch("url", {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(globalUsername + ":" + globalPassword),
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: moveBody
        }).then(response => console.log(response.status)).
        then(response => console.log(response.text(body)));
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What do you want to achieve? This question is not clear at all.

Comment: `.then(response => console.log(response.status))` is transforming the response to `undefined` (the returned value of `console.log`)

Answer (score 6):

[`Promise.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) can be chained [`Promise.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) parameter is object returned from previous [`Promise.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) chain

[`Response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) return string body

[`Response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) return parsed json

```js
fetch("url", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(globalUsername + ":" + globalPassword),
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: moveBody
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response.status) || response) // output the status and return response
  .then(response => response.text()) // send response body to next then chain
  .then(body => console.log(body)) // you can use response body here
```

Comment: Does response.text() always work, even if the content type is json?

Comment: Yes, However if you need the value of the json you need to parse the json manually using `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [Response.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text):

```
fetch(url,...).then(response => response.text()).then(console.log)
```

Comment: How to let body as a string? such as let a = body?

Comment: @Phosphorusred `fetch(url,...).then(response => body = response.text())` I suggest to study Promises a bit more before proceeding further.